# Executing a looping python script via a Django web page

Tags: python, django

Looking for some guidance or advice. I am running a Django app on a Raspberry Pi that serves it locally. The purpose of this project is to run a looping python script on the raspberry pi that records data from a scale (Load cell) twice every second using the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi. The goal is to have a django webpage where a user can start and stop the python script and view the live weight data that is measured by the script.

**How do I have a start and stop button for this python script on a django web page and have it add the output data from the script to my database?**

Comment: I think channels should be suited for this. Channels is based on an asyncronous event loop. You can take a look at the [community projects](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community.html) page for some examples of projects that are not traditional request/response web apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand Channels would be used to show the live data on the webpage, but how would I execute the python script from django. Would I use channels for that as well?